# start new application from my own application using intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

How we can start a other application from my application in android?currently am using the following code for the same but it shows error in logcat .please check my code and the error message and please give some suggestions.

```
sample code
package com.example.testintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.abcd.main", "com.abcd.main.SplashScreenActivity");
        intent.setComponent(component );
        startActivity(intent);  



    }

}
```

logcat error

```
03-29 15:17:06.857: W/dalvikvm(5051): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c601f8)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.abcd.main/com.abcd.main.SplashScreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1511)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1387)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3195)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3302)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at com.example.testintent.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
03-29 15:17:06.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How we can start a other application from my application in android?

Call `startActivity()` on a valid, exported activity.

> it shows error in logcat

`com.abcd.main.SplashScreenActivity`, in the `com.abcd.main` app, is not a valid, exported activity.

Comment: @skyblueandroid007: `com.abcd.main` does not have a `com.abcd.main.SplashScreenActivity`, or that activity is not marked as exported (e.g., it has no `<intent-filter>`).

Comment: how can i achieve this ,means how can i open a another application from my application